# Lock otimista; por que não dispara exceção?

Tags: java, hibernate, lock

Tentei simular uma situação de Lock otimista onde se tenta atualizar o mesmo registro duas vezes, porem a excessao nao é disparada.

Acho interessante é que mesmo depois de alterar o valor do titular e dar um MERGE, o valor de versao nao é atualizado no objeto e nem no registro da base.

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("financas");
    EntityManager em1 = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityManager em2 = emf.createEntityManager();

    em1.getTransaction().begin();
    em2.getTransaction().begin();

    Conta c1 = em1.find(Conta.class,1);
    em1.lock(c1, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
    em1.merge(c1);
    em1.getTransaction().commit();
    Conta c2 = em2.find(Conta.class,1);
    em2.lock(c2, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
    em2.merge(c2);
    em2.getTransaction().commit();
```

------------- ATUALIZADO ---------------------

Conteudo da classe conta:

```
package br.com.financas.modelo;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
public class Conta {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String titular;
    private String banco;
    private String agencia;
    private String numero;

    @Version
    private int versao;

    public int getVersao() {
        return versao;
    }
    public void setVersao(int versao) {
        this.versao = versao;
    }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="conta")
    private List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitular() {
        return titular;
    }
    public void setTitular(String titular) {
        this.titular = titular;
    }
    public String getBanco() {
        return banco;
    }
    public void setBanco(String banco) {
        this.banco = banco;
    }
    public String getAgencia() {
        return agencia;
    }
    public void setAgencia(String agencia) {
        this.agencia = agencia;
    }
    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }
    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    public List<Movimentacao> getMovimentacoes() {
        return movimentacoes;
    }
    public void setMovimentacoes(List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes) {
        this.movimentacoes = movimentacoes;
    }


}
```

Porque a exceção nao é lançada?

Comment: Poderias por gentileza disponibilizar o código fonte da classe Conta.java?

Comment: O caso que você está testando é o mesmo que colocou aqui? No exemplo que você colocou na sua pergunta, você não faz nenhuma alteração em algum atributo da `Conta`, dessa forma, nenhuma exceção será lançada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A exceção não é lançada por dois motivos:

**1)** Não foi feita nenhuma alteração na entidade nem no primeiro nem no segundo contexto em que ela foi obtida e persistida, logo não há como haver conflito no segundo contexto.

**2)** A transação do primeiro contexto foi concluída (foi feito *commit*) antes de a entidade ter sido obtida no segundo contexto. Então mesmo que não houvesse o problema *1*, ainda assim não haveria exceção pois entre a obtenção e persistência da entidade no segundo contexto nenhuma alteração foi feita em outro contexto.

Para que houvesse exceção, o código precisa estar mais ou menos assim:

```
Conta c1 = em1.find(Conta.class,1);
em1.lock(c1, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
c1.setNumero(novoNumero);       // linha adicionada
em1.merge(c1);
//em1.getTransaction().commit();   linha removida
Conta c2 = em2.find(Conta.class,1);
em2.lock(c2, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
em1.getTransaction().commit();  // linha adicionada
c2.setNumero(aindaOutroNumero); // linha adicionada
em2.merge(c2);
em2.getTransaction().commit();
```

No código acima, a coluna *version* foi atualizada e persistida depois de a entidade ser novamente obtida em outro contexto. Então quando a entidade é finalmente persistida no outro contexto, o valor de *version* encontrado na base é diferente daquele existente na entidade em memória, o que fará lançar uma exceção de *"o registro foi alterado por outro usuário"*.